# Resources in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resources

I am trying to add a `myimage.jpg` as a resource in Visual Studio 2013 for a C# project. I need to dynamically load these resources. I added the `myimage.jpg` to the resources of the project and set it as a embedded resource. Then in my code I try to use the resource by using

```
pictureBox1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.myimage
```

but the choices I have after `Resources.` are culture, equals, reference equals and resource manager. Why is `myimage` not a choice?

Comment: Have you tryed to compile your project between the time you added the ressource and the time you actually tryed to use it ?

Comment: try adding in image source property,if it is available

Answer (score 0):

This works correctly for me.   I added a JPG image to the resources tab in project properties, then loaded the image into a picturebox with the following code:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources._17080
```

The image appeared in the picturebox as expected.

This also works when I specifically reference the form:

```
WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources._17080
```

If you are instead creating a custom resources file (Resource1.resx), then you can use this:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Resource1._17808
```

Comment: I get the following message when I try that 
Error 1 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources' does not contain a definition for '_17080'

To add the resource I right clicked on resource and did add, then add existing item.

Comment: mine is called myimage and I get Error 1 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources' does not contain a definition for myimage.  I have no idea what I am doing wrong

Comment: Could you share with us?  Just in case someone else has a similar issue?